# Need code to make animation to stop

Tags: actionscript

Trying to stop this animation on frame 109 in as2. Any help in what I need to ad to get this to stop. It is a confetti animation.

```
cnfNumber = 85;
var cnfs:Array = new Array("cnf", "cnf2", "cnf3","cnf4","cnf5") 
for (i=0; i<cnfNumber; i++) {
    newCnf = _root[cnfs[random(cnfs.length)]].duplicateMovieClip("snow"+i, i);
    newCnf._x = Math.random()*Stage.width;
    newCnf._y = -Math.random()*300;
    newCnf.maxCnfSpeed = Math.random()*4;
    newCnf.wind = Math.random()*6;
    newCnf._xscale = newCnf._yscale = newCnf.alpha = Math.random()*65+35
    newCnf.onEnterFrame = function() {
        this._rotation -= this.maxCnfSpeed+1;
        if(this._y>Stage.height || this._x>Stage.width || this._x<0){
            this._y = -Math.random()*300;
            this._x = Math.random()*Stage.width;
        } else {
            this._y += this.maxCnfSpeed+2;
            this._x += this.wind-4;
        }

        this._alpha = this.alpha;
    };
}
```

Comment: This is actionscript not javascript, right?

Comment: Yes, cnfs:Array is valid actionscript.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this:

```
newCnf._xscale = newCnf._yscale = newCnf.alpha = Math.random()*65+35
newCnf.frameCount = 0;
newCnf.onEnterFrame = function() {
    if(this.frameCount<109) {
        this._rotation -= this.maxCnfSpeed+1;
        if(this._y>Stage.height || this._x>Stage.width || this._x<0){
            this._y = -Math.random()*300;
            this._x = Math.random()*Stage.width;
        } else {
            this._y += this.maxCnfSpeed+2;
            this._x += this.wind-4;
        }
        this._alpha = this.alpha;
        this.frameCount++;
    } else {
        this.onEnterFrame = null;
    }
};
```

I haven't worked in Actionscript in a while, so the `this.onEnterFrame = null` may not be quite correct, but it's not strictly necessary; it just keeps the confetti from checking the frame number and bailing out every frame once it's done animating.

If you want the confetti to disappear rather than freezing in place, unload it instead of clearing its `onEnterFrame`. I don't remember the function that does that off the top of my head, but the documentation for `duplicateMovieClip` should have a link to it.

(I won't ask why you're still using AS2.)